# Add scrollbar using CSS

Tags: css

The current CSS I am using is below. I have looked at online tutorials and help and tried to put a scrollbar in the main body/content section as the information in my tables overflow the space into the aside section. What do I do to add a scrollbar if the content overflows?

```css
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
    background: #fff;
}

#header {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
}

#header h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

#navigation {
    float: left;
    width: 900px;
    background: #333;
}

#navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navigation ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

#navigation li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

#navigation li a:hover {
    background: #383;
}

#content-container {
    float: left;
    width: 900px;
    background: #fff url(/wp-content/uploads/layout-two-fixed-background.gif) repeat-y 100% 0;
}

#content {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    width: 560px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
    display: inline;
}

#content h2 {
    margin: 0;
}

#aside {
    float: right;
    width: 240px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    display: inline;
}

#aside h3 {
    margin: 0;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `overflow` of the parent div to `scroll`. Thats all. Checkout the following link for the demo.
 [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zb4n0bf3/)

Answer (score 0):

In order for content to "overflow" it needs some sort of set height and then you add overflow: scroll to your css.

Example:

```
.myClass {
     overflow: scroll;
     height: 300px;
     width: 300px;
}
```

You can also do

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

or

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

if you want to restrict it to one directional scrolling.

Here is some more info on the overflow property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Here is a working example:

```css
.myClass {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
  <p>This is my scrollable content</p>
    <p>This is my scrollable content</p>
    <p>This is my scrollable content</p>
    <p>This is my scrollable content</p>
    <p>This is my scrollable content</p>
    <p>This is my scrollable content</p>
    <p>This is my scrollable content</p>
    <p>This is my scrollable content</p>
    <p>More Content</p>
      <p>More Content</p>
      <p>More Content</p>
      <p>More Content</p>
      <p>More Content</p>
      <p>More Content</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overflow-y attribute to your content div to add a scroll bar once it has reached its max height.

Example:

```
#content{
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Note: This above will only work if the content div has a fixed height.

You can also do the following:

```
#content{
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Note: This will add a scroll bar to the x an y axis no matter the size of the div. So I recommend the first way.

Answer (score 0):

use a div tag to wrap table :

```
<div>
  <table>
  </table>
</div>
```

then :

```
div
{
  width : 40px; // depends on your table width and height you want to show at certain area
  height: 40px;
  overflow-y:hidden; // depends on having a scroll bar at vertical or horizontal direction
  overflow-x:auto;
}
```